# How do I write a Rust unit test that ensures that a panic has occurred?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a Rust function that `panic`s under some condition and I wish to write a test case to validate whether the function is panicking or not. I couldn't find anything except the `assert!` and `assert_eq!` macros. Is there some mechanism for testing this?

I could spawn a new task and checking whether that task panics or not. Does it make sense?

---

Returning a `Result<T, E>` is not suitable in my case.

I wish to add support for the `Add` trait to a `Matrix` type I am implementing. The ideal syntax for such addition would look like:

```
let m = m1 + m2 + m3;
```

where `m1`, `m2`, `m3` are all matrices. Hence, the result type of `add` should be `Matrix`. Something like the following would be too cryptic:

```
let m = ((m1 + m2).unwrap() + m3).unwrap()
```

At the same time, the `add()` function needs to validate that the two matrices being added have same dimension. Thus, `add()` needs to panic if the dimensions don't match.  The available option is `panic!()`.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can find the answer in [testing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html#checking-for-panics-with-should_panic) section of the Rust book. More specifically, you want `#[should_panic]` attribute:

```
#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn test_invalid_matrices_multiplication() {
    let m1 = Matrix::new(3, 4);  // assume these are dimensions
    let m2 = Matrix::new(5, 6);
    m1 * m2
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can add a check for the panic's text: `#[should_panic(expected = "assertion failed")]`

Comment: A quick note here that depending on your IDE and environment the stack trace from the panic may still appear in the output, but the test will still pass. It took me a minute to realize that my `#[should_panic]` was actually working. When you run a generic `cargo test` from the command line you'll notice that it swallows the panic and just shows as `ok`.

Comment: I would strengthen that "can" to "*really should*". Code can panic in many ways. If you don't specify an expected text, the test could end up passing for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 89):

As Francis Gagné mentioned in his answer, I also find the `#[should_panic]` attribute (as suggested by the accepted answer) is not fine-grained enough.  For example, if my test setup fails for some reason (i.e. I've written a bad test), I *do* want a panic to be considered a failure!

As of Rust 1.9.0, [`std::panic::catch_unwind()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) is available.  It allows you to put the code you expect to panic into a closure, and only panics emitted by *that* code will be considered expected (i.e. a passing test).

```
#[test]
fn test_something() {
    ... //<-- Any panics here will cause test failure (good)
    let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| <expected_to_panic_operation_here>);
    assert!(result.is_err());  //probe further for specific error type here, if desired
}
```

Note it cannot catch non-unwinding panics (e.g. `std::process::abort()`).

Answer (score 31):

If you want to assert that only a specific portion of the test function fails, use [`std::panic::catch_unwind()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) and check that it returns an `Err`, for example with [`is_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.is_err). In complex test functions, this helps ensure that the test doesn't pass erroneously because of an early failure.

[Several](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a1bad57fa59a8069a6ebb05cd6a2ae73c88b2e98/src/test/run-pass/panic-uninitialized-zeroed.rs) [tests](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a1bad57fa59a8069a6ebb05cd6a2ae73c88b2e98/src/test/run-pass/running-with-no-runtime.rs) in the Rust standard library itself use this technique.

Comment: Should there be an `assert_fails` or `assert_panics` macro for this?

Comment: You can use [`unwrap_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_err) too.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a `#[no_std]` environment? I'm looking to create an `assert_panics!` macro for general use.

Comment: @jhpratt The best I've found for `#[no_std]` so far is to use  #[should_panic(expected = "<panic message to match>")] with `unreachable!()` following the should-panic test condition.  Test is green with expected panic, red otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

Use following `catch_unwind_silent` instead of regular `catch_unwind` to achieve silence in output for expected exceptions:

```
use std::panic;

fn catch_unwind_silent<F: FnOnce() -> R + panic::UnwindSafe, R>(f: F) -> std::thread::Result<R> {
    let prev_hook = panic::take_hook();
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| {}));
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(f);
    panic::set_hook(prev_hook);
    result
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As an addendum: The solution proposed by @U007D also works in doctests:

````
/// My identity function that panic for an input of 42.
///
/// ```
/// assert_eq!(my_crate::my_func(23), 23);
///
/// let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| my_crate::my_func(42));
/// assert!(result.is_err());
/// ```
pub fn my_func(input: u32) -> u32 {
    if input == 42 {
        panic!("Error message.");
    } else {
        input
    }
}
````

Answer (score 3):

From the Documentation on Unit testing, in the [Testing Panics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/unit_testing.html#testing-panics) section

```rust
pub fn divide_non_zero_result(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    if b == 0 {
        panic!("Divide-by-zero error");
    } else if a < b {
        panic!("Divide result is zero");
    }
    a / b
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_divide() {
        assert_eq!(divide_non_zero_result(10, 2), 5);
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn test_any_panic() {
        divide_non_zero_result(1, 0);
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic(expected = "Divide result is zero")]
    fn test_specific_panic() {
        divide_non_zero_result(1, 10);
    }
}
```

The output when running `cargo test` would be

```bash
$ cargo test

running 2 tests
test tests::test_bad_add ... FAILED
test tests::test_add ... ok

failures:

---- tests::test_bad_add stdout ----
        thread 'tests::test_bad_add' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `-1`,
 right: `3`', src/lib.rs:21:8
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.


failures:
    tests::test_bad_add

test result: FAILED. 1 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issues with the accepted answer with using `#[should_panic]` attributes are:

- unrelated panics might cause a test to pass
- it does not suppress the printing of the panic message to the console, resulting in unclean test execution log
- it is not possible to add additional checks after the panic has happened

As a better alternative, I would highly recommend **checking out the library called [fluent-asserter](https://github.com/mirind4/fluent-asserter)**

By using it, you can easily write an assertion that checks if a panic has occurred, as follows:

```
#[test]
fn assert_that_code_panics() {
    let panicking_action = || panic!("some panic message");

    assert_that_code!(panicking_action)
        .panics()
        .with_message("some panic message");
}
```

The good thing with this is that:

- it uses a fluent interface, resulting in a readable assertion
- it suppresses the printing of the panic message to the console, resulting in a clean test execution log
- you can add additional assertions after the panic check

Answer (score 0):

When using rust crate [`test_case`](https://docs.rs/test-case/2.2.1/test_case/index.html), use the `panics` idiom.

```rust
extern crate test_case;
use test_case::test_case;

#[test_case(0 => panics)]
#[test_case(1)]
fn test_divisor(divisor: usize) {
    let _result = 1 / divisor;
}
```