# How do you test for a specific Rust error?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, error-handling, rust

I can find ways to detect if Rust gives me an error,

```
assert!(fs::metadata(path).is_err())
```

[source](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/idiomatic-way-of-testing-result-t-error/2171/2)

How do I test for a specific error?

Comment: You can use macro #[should_panic].
You can have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26470361/8402395

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can directly compare the returned `Err` variant if it `impl Debug + PartialEq`:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum MyError {
    TooBig,
    TooSmall,
}

pub fn encode(&self, decoded: &'a Bytes) -> Result<&'a Bytes, MyError> {
    if decoded.len() > self.length() as usize {
        Err(MyError::TooBig)
    } else {
        Ok(&decoded)
    }
}
```

```
assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&[1]), Err(MyError::TooBig));
```

Comment: *get the `Option` from `Result` with `.err`* — why not just compare directly?

Comment: @Shepmaster `Option` is not a variant of `Result`. Not sure if I understand your question. Also just started programming Rust yesterday so might be missing something obvious here

Comment: Why not compare with `Err(MyError::TooBig)`?

Comment: When I try I get `expected enum 'std::result::Result', found enum 'fixed::Error'`

Comment: @AakilFernandes Can you show the code resulting in this error?

Comment: @SvenMarnach `assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&[1]), Error::TooBig);`

Comment: `Err(MyError::TooBig)` is not the same as `MyError::TooBig`

Comment: @Shepmaster the Error/MyError thing is just cause I'm locally editing my version as we speak and copy/pasting

Comment: **Err(** foo **)** is not the same as foo, just like `Some(MyError::TooBig)` is not the same as `MyError::TooBig`.

Comment: Uploaded a gist so we could be working from the same code :) https://gist.github.com/aakilfernandes/7d6258ee18f91e5399f90239c6bf65b4

Comment: @AakilFernandes Shepmaster is suggesting you use `assert_eq!(fixed.encode(&[1]), Err(Error::TooBig));`.

Comment: Your function returns `Err(MyError::TooBig)` – literally.  You now want to know whether the function returned `Err(MyError::TooBig)`, so you compare the return value to `Err(MyError::TooBig)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks for sticking with me. I still get an error when trying that

Comment: > thread 'fixed::tests::fixed_0' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: TooBig'

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aakilfernandes/7d6258ee18f91e5399f90239c6bf65b4#file-fixed-rs-L58

Comment: @AakilFernandes That's completely unrelated – none of the code you showed so far uses `unwrap()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183030/discussion-between-aakil-fernandes-and-sven-marnach).

Comment: I see the code in the last line has been edited, but now it doesn't match what is said in the first line. The first line should probably be updated to match the code.

Answer (score 13):

Following solution doesn't require `PartialEq` trait to be implemented. For instance `std::io::Error` does not implement this, and more general solution is required.

In these cases, you can borrow a macro `assert_matches` from [matches crate](https://crates.io/crates/matches). It works by giving more succinct way to pattern match, the macro is so short you can just type it too:

```rust
macro_rules! assert_err {
    ($expression:expr, $($pattern:tt)+) => {
        match $expression {
            $($pattern)+ => (),
            ref e => panic!("expected `{}` but got `{:?}`", stringify!($($pattern)+), e),
        }
    }
}

// Example usages:
assert_err!(your_func(), Err(Error::UrlParsingFailed(_)));
assert_err!(your_func(), Err(Error::CanonicalizationFailed(_)));
assert_err!(your_func(), Err(Error::FileOpenFailed(er)) if er.kind() == ErrorKind::NotFound);
```

Full playground buildable example, with example `Error` enum:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    UrlCreationFailed,
    CanonicalizationFailed(std::io::Error),
    FileOpenFailed(std::io::Error),
    UrlParsingFailed(url::ParseError),
}

pub fn your_func() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::io::ErrorKind;
    use super::{your_func, Error};

    macro_rules! assert_err {
        ($expression:expr, $($pattern:tt)+) => {
            match $expression {
                $($pattern)+ => (),
                ref e => panic!("expected `{}` but got `{:?}`", stringify!($($pattern)+), e),
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_failures() {
        // Few examples are here:
        assert_err!(your_func(), Err(Error::UrlParsingFailed(_)));
        assert_err!(your_func(), Err(Error::CanonicalizationFailed(_)));
        assert_err!(your_func(), Err(Error::FileOpenFailed(er)) if er.kind() == ErrorKind::NotFound);
    }

}
```